# Number of key values for dictionary not coming out correctly

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

When trying to assign Grades to Test_Scores (which when the average is calculated), only returns two assigned dictionaries. For some reason, the last one won't show up. How would I get the third dictionary to show up?

```
Test_Scores = [{'test_1': 90, 'test_2': 80, 'test_3': 95},
 {'test_1': 92, 'test_2': 75, 'test_3': 80},
 {'test_1': 80, 'feature_2': 81, 'test_3': 82}]

Grades = ['A', 'B', 'B']

Empty_dict = {}
Empty_dict = dict(zip(Grades, Test_Scores))
print(Empty_dict)
```

I expect something like:

```
{'A': {'test_1': 90, 'test_2': 80, 'test_3': 95}, 'B': {'test_1': 92, 
'test_2': 75, 'test_3': 80}, {'test_1': 80, 'feature_2': 81, 'test_3': 
82}})
```

to demonstrate the average of the three tests is that assigned key.

However, I get:

```
{'A': {'test_1': 90, 'test_2': 80, 'test_3': 95}, 'B': {'test_1': 80, 
'feature_2': 81, 'test_3': 82}}
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing `dict(zip(Grades, Test_Scores))` you override the value of `B` with the last occurrence, instead you could do:

```
Empty_dict = {}
for score, grade in zip(Test_Scores, Grades):
    Empty_dict.setdefault(grade, []).append(score)

print(Empty_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{'A': [{'test_1': 90, 'test_2': 80, 'test_3': 95}], 'B': [{'test_1': 92, 'test_2': 75, 'test_3': 80}, {'test_1': 80, 'feature_2': 81, 'test_3': 82}]}
```